# How to assign a value using a siddhi query?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I need to assign a value to a particular attribute in a stream by checking a condition.

How do I do it?

e.g

if a person's name is 'John' and I need to modify his name into 'Peter' and insert into another stream,  how do I do it?

```
from myStream [name == 'John']
select *
insert into outStream;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
define stream myStream (name string, attribute1 int, attribute2 bool);

from myStream [name == 'John']                  --This filter matches any event with name equal to 'John'
select "Peter" as name, attribute1, attribute2  --Replaces the current name with 'Peter'
insert into outStream;
```

Example 1

Input:

```
{Dilini, 123, true}
```

Output:

(there'll be no output, since the name doesn't satisfy the condition in the filter, name=='John')

Example 2

Input:

```
{John, 123, true}
```

Output:

```
{Peter, 123, true}
```

Refer ['Query Projection' capabilities in Siddhi](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.0#SiddhiQLGuide3.0-QueryProjection). Check the action: *'Introducing the default value'*.

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Comment: It wasn't about me, I don't even know what this is all about. Stumbled upon your answer in the review queue and thought it could need a bit of explanation to improve usefulness for others.